# Showing error while adding addtional field in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="registerTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Register
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="registerContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Create a New Account</h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to create a new account. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%: ViewData["PasswordLength"] %> characters in length.
    </p>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>

            **<div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FirstName)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)%>
            </div>**

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

In this code I'm adding a new field in the name of `FirstName`, but I get an error:

> 'MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Does your `RegisterModel` contains `FirstName` property? Did you add new property to `RegisterModel` class ?

Comment: No, how to add this field in register model

Comment: just add.... Public string FirstName {get;set;} in registermodel

Answer (score 0):

Adding new property to the view is not enough.

Add `public string FirstName{ get; set; }` to your `RegisterModel` class.

It should be like below.

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    // other properties

    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```